# Delphi 2010: Firebird dbExpress Error Unable to load dbxfb4d14.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, dbexpress

I just downloaded the **dbExpress Driver for Firebird** by Chee-Yang Chau from this [google code site](http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/home).

I loaded the Delphi 2010 demo projects and tried running it and immediatedly got a could not load dll error:

[image: dbxfb4dl14.dll error]

**INI File**
`[Installed Drivers]
FirebirdConnection=1`

[FirebirdConnection]
;DriverUnit=DBXInterBase
;DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver120.bpl
;DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
;MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxInterBaseDriver120.bpl
;MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxInterBaseDriver,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverFIREBIRD
LibraryName=dbxfb4d14.dll
VendorLib=C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_1_5\bin\fbclient.dll
BlobSize=-1
CommitRetain=False
Database=database.gdb
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Password=masterkey
RoleName=RoleName
ServerCharSet=
SQLDialect=3
Interbase TransIsolation=ReadCommited
User_Name=sysdba
WaitOnLocks=True
Trim Char=False

**Delphi Code**

`procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var C: TSQLConnection;
begin
  C := TSQLConnection.Create(Self);
  try
    C.DriverName := 'FirebirdConnection';
//    C.LibraryName := 'dbxufb40.dll';
//    C.VendorLib := 'C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_1_5\bin\fbclient.dll';
//    C.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverFIREBIRD';
    C.Params.Add('User_Name=SYSDBA');
    C.Params.Add('Password=masterkey');
    C.Params.Add('Database=localhost:%ProgramFiles%\Firebird\Firebird_1_5\examples\employee.fdb');
    C.Open;
    if C.Connected then
      ShowMessage('Connection is active')
  finally
    C.Free;
  end;
end;`
I noticed that the library name **dbxfb4d14.dll** in the ini file did not match the actual dll name **dbxfb4d15.dll** so I modified the ini file so it would match the name of the dll.

Now I get an error saying the **dbxfb4d15.dll** cannot be found.

[image: dbxfb4d15 error]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need the d14 version for Delphi 2010. The d15 version is for XE. Not sure why there is only the d15 version in the zip.

The DLL is not located on your DLL search path. Once you get hold of the right DLL then you need to make sure it's on the path.

Having browsed around this component I'm not convinced it's terribly polished. If you can afford it, the Devart drivers come highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you. How did you find out that d15 is for XE and d14 is for 2010? Also, I looked at Devart's Firebird order page and it describes the MySql dbExpress driver. I sent them an email. http://www.devart.com/dbx/interbase/ordering.html

Comment: I just read the readme file and saw the reference to d14. Do you have a preference of which Devart component Unidac seems more versatile than either the single VCL components or the dbExpress components?

Comment: Just e-mail Devart. They know their product best of all. They will give you sound advice.